# nicEditor some items not working to display

Tags: php, html, nicedit

I'm using `NicEdit` with `image upload` option.
I'd tested my site on `localhost` and everything works well. But as I've uploaded it to the `server` it doesn't work.
I found the reason is that, it is adding `\` to every `"`. And the tags I'm getting looks like:

```
<img src=\"http://someurl.com/image.jpg\">
```

How could I tackle with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd found the reason of such behavior.
I'm using `addslashes($str)` for avoiding user to enter any escape sequence. But I forgot to use `stripslashes($str)` for removing `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Faisal you can replace all \ with the "" (empty space). just use

```
private String replace(String Path){


        return Path.replaceAll("\\", "");

    }
```